# JavaScript - scrollIntoView() only works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg, js-scrollintoview

I'm trying to `scrollIntoView()` on a SVG element. It works on Firefox as intended but on Chrome and Edge it scrolls down too far or some other place that is wrong.

```
<g id="clust1" class="cluster">
    <title>cluster_Legend</title>
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="8,-8 8,-59 2503,-59 2503,-8 8,-8"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="1255.5" y="-47" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="10.00">Node color legend </text>
</g>
```

I have a variable `selectedCluster` with the selected `<g>` element. I call `scrollIntoView`() on the `<polygon>` nested within the `<g>` element.

```
var polygon = selectedCluster.querySelector("polygon");
polygon.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

How do I make it so that it scrolls correctly in Chrome and Edge?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a [known fixed Chrome bug](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/5d6edb4f084778cf635640c4fafd65418af841f7), not sure when you could expect to see this in production.

Comment: Alright thanks, I guess I'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: Try looking stuff up on caniuse first please. Like @ShengSlogar said, it's a known bug (in most major browsers actually), but only for the "smooth" option. https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView
Edit: Look at this polyfill, don't know if it works for svgs: http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/

Comment: Bookmarked, didn't know of its existence. With the smooth option off I get the same result, it just snaps to the wrong place instead.

Comment: Correct, smooth `scrollIntoView` doesn't have great support but that isn't related to your problem. You're probably better off just finding some way to finagle numbers and calculate your own scroll position. [See this related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51008191/2535504)

Comment: Are there any non-vanilla js scrollIntoView() alternatives?